# Compare split and merge two dataframe

Tags: r

How to compare two datasets df1 and df2 by Gene names and extract the corresponding values for each gene names from df2 and insert it in to df1

```
df1 <-

Genes    sample.ID  chrom   loc.start   loc.end num.mark
Klri2     LO.WGS      1   3010000 173490000     8430
Rrs1      LO.WGS      1   3010000 173490000     8430
Serpin    LO.WGS      1   3010000 173490000     8430
Myoc      LO.WGS          1   3010000 173490000     8430
St18      LO.WGS          1   3010000 173490000     8430


df2 <-

    RL  pValue.   chr   start            end    CNA     Genes
    2   2.594433   1    129740006   129780779   gain    Klri2   
    2   3.941399   1    130080653   130380997   gain    Serpin,St18,Myoc

df3<-

Genes   sample.ID  chrom  loc.start  loc.end num.mark   RL  pValue      CNA
Klri2    LO.WGS     1   3010000   173490000     8430    2   2.594433    gain
Rrs1     LO.WGS     1   3010000   173490000     8430    0     0          0
Serpin   LO.WGS     1   3010000   173490000     8430    2   3.941399    gain
Myoc     LO.WGS     1   3010000   173490000     8430    2   3.941399    gain
St18     LO.WGS     1   3010000   173490000     8430    2   3.941399    gain
```

Comment: here is a great introduction to dplyr. It's a package used to merge and select particular columns in R. It is very useful and worth reading. Much more valuable than this specific problem. [link](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) If it still doesn't help, then come back and ask specific questions referencing what you tried and the result you got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
library(splitstackshape)   
out <- cSplit(df2, "Genes", sep = ",", "long")
```

This will reshape `df2` in the proper format (one row for each gene):

```
#   RL  pValue. chr     start       end  CNA  Genes
#1:  2 2.594433   1 129740006 129780779 gain  Klri2
#2:  2 3.941399   1 130080653 130380997 gain Serpin
#3:  2 3.941399   1 130080653 130380997 gain   St18
#4:  2 3.941399   1 130080653 130380997 gain   Myoc
```

Then you simply have to use `merge()` or `left_join()` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- left_join(df1, out)
```

If you want to replace `NA`s by `0`, you could do:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, out) %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))
```

Or, if you prefer subsetting:

```
df3 <- left_join(df1, out) %>% (function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x })
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a merge operation but first you have to bring `df2` in the right format, which will contain one row for each gene (rather than a single entry for multiple genes separated by comma). There is a convenient function to do this from the `tidyr` package, `unnest()`

```
df2 <- tidyr::unnest(
         transform(df2, Genes = strsplit(as.character(df2$Genes), ",")),
         Genes)
```

The result looks like this

```
df2
#  RL  pValue. chr     start       end  CNA  Genes
#1  2 2.594433   1 129740006 129780779 gain  Klri2
#2  2 3.941399   1 130080653 130380997 gain Serpin
#3  2 3.941399   1 130080653 130380997 gain   St18
#4  2 3.941399   1 130080653 130380997 gain   Myoc
```

Now you can simply use `merge(df1, df2, all.x = TRUE)` or `left_join` from `dplyr` (or other packages like `data.table`, depending on which one you want to learn). Note that this will introduce `NA`s where you want to have zeros but you can easily replace these.